# Why does STDIN cause my Perl program to freeze?

Tags: perl, stdin, activeperl

I am learning Perl and wrote this script to practice using STDIN. When I run the script, it only shows the first print statement on the console. No matter what I type in, including new lines, the console doesn't show the next print statement. (I'm using ActivePerl on a Windows machine.) It looks like this:

```
$perl script.pl
What is the exchange rate? 90.45
[Cursor stays here]
```

This is my script:

```
#!/user/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;

print "What is the exchange rate? ";
my @exchangeRate = <STDIN>;
chomp(@exchangeRate);

print "What is the value you would like to convert? ";
chomp(my @otherCurrency = <STDIN>);

my @result = @otherCurrency / @exchangeRate;
print "The result is @{result}.\n";
```

One potential solution I noticed while researching my problem is that I could include

```
use IO::Handle;
```

and

```
flush STDIN; flush STDOUT;
```

in my script. These lines did not solve my problem, though.

What should I do to have STDIN behave normally? If this is normal behavior, what am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you do

```
my @answer = <STDIN>;
```

...Perl waits for the `EOF` character (on Unix and Unix-like it's Ctrl-D). Then, each line you input (separated by linefeeds) go into the list.

If you instead do:

```
my $answer = <STDIN>;
```

...Perl waits for a linefeed, then puts the string you entered into `$answer`.

Comment: On UNIX and UNIX-like system the end of line character is linefeed, not carriage return.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that I wasn't using a scalar after I made my post. >_< Thanks for pointing out how to use STDIN with an array!

Answer (score 5):

I found my problem. I was using the wrong type of variable. Instead of writing:

```
my @exchangeRate = <STDIN>;
```

I should have used:

```
my $exchangeRate = <STDIN>;
```

with a $ instead of a @.

Answer (score 4):

To end multiline input, you can use Control-D on Unix or Control-Z on Windows.

However, you probably just wanted a single line of input, so you should have used a scalar like other people mentioned. *Learning Perl* walks you through this sort of stuff.

Answer (score -3):

You could try and enable autoflush.

Either

```
use IO::Handle;
STDOUT->autoflush(1);
```

or

```
$| = 1;
```

That's why you are not seeing the output printed.

Also, you need to change from arrays '@' to scalar variables '$'

```
$val = <STDIN>;
chomp($val);
```